# Why is ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server converting strings to dates automatically and how can I stop this?

Tags: sql-server, linux, python-3.6, unixodbc

I'm moving an app that was previously running on windows 10 to a docker container with python3.6 linux base image. One of the necessary changes was changing the driver used in sql connection string from "SQL Server" to ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, because I have to use unixodbc-dev. I installed msodbcsql17 and mssql-tools via my Dockerfile, and I execute a query via an sqlalchemy engine that retrieves values from a column of sql type "date". With the SQL Server driver, these dates get converted to strings (which is what the code expects), but with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, they are returned as dates. I'm using pyodbc==4.0.25 and SQLAlchemy==1.3.5.

Comment: Why would you want a `date` column to be returned as a string data type in the first place..? A string data type is, by definition, *not* a `date`.

Comment: @Larnu that's a very valid point, and one I'm going to raise with my team, but in the meantime I wanted to work around this without changing the code and potentially breaking something

Comment: In my opinion, the driver is working correctly. If you want to return a string data type to the application layer, you need to define it as one in your SQL.

Comment: @Larnu so does this mean that the SQL Server driver does not work correctly? Because that one does return a string... I was wondering is there is some configurable option somewhere that's triggering this.

Comment: It's been a some time since I used the SQL Server driver, if I am honest; it's been deprecated for some time. With no code, or [mre], impossible to state, but I wouldn't expect it to change the data types no; I would suggest that a major flaw if so.

Comment: @Boris, the legacy "SQL Server" ODBC driver hasn't been enhanced since SQL 2000, long before the newer `date` data type (and other temporal types) was introduced.  The driver will return unrecognized types as strings instead of the native type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legacy "SQL Server" ODBC driver hasn't been enhanced since SQL Server 2000, long before the newer date data type (and other temporal types) was introduced with SQL Server 2008. The driver will return unrecognized types as strings instead of the native type.

If the native type is a breaking change for the app code, the correct solution is to use proper types in app code and the newer driver. About all you can do is use the legacy driver in the interim.